# How do message publishers advise clients about queue URLs?

Tags: java, message-queue, amazon-sqs

In Amazon SQS, message publishers create queues and publish messages onto them. However, to consume messages from a queue, client(s) need to know of the queue URL, which (apparently) only the publisher knows.

Am I missing something here on how queue architectures work?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something here on how queue architectures work?

I suspect so.

Queues have producers and consumers... but neither of these entities necessarily creates the queue.  Both of them must -- by some mechanism -- learn the URL, of course, but how that happens is entirely dependent on the application.

A queue (thus its URL) is often permanent (not transient) and created in the provisioning process (automated or manual) -- not by the producer.

While it's possible for the producer to create the queue, it's also possible for the consumer to create the queue, and then (directly or indirectly) advise the process that ultimately becomes the producer where to send whatever message will be sent.

It's also not uncommon for a worker process to be a consumer of one queue and a producer to another... or for workers to interact with multiple queues.

```
"W" = workers, "P" = producer, "C" = consumer, "Q" = queue, "T" = task

W1 (now a producer) >> Q1 >> "Please perform task T1 and send results to Q2"
W2 (now a consumer) << Q1 << "Please perform task T1 and send results to Q2"
W2 (performs task T1)
W2 (now a producer) >> Q2 >> "Here are the results from task T1"
W1 (now a consumer) << Q2 << "Here are the results from task T1"
```

In this example, W1 is a producer for Q1 and a consumer of Q2; it needs to know both the URL for Q1 (where to send request) and Q2 (where to ask for response to be sent).  The producer for Q1 likely would not be responsible for creating Q1.  Q1 would already exist.  It *might* be responsible for creating Q2, for which it will be a consumer.

Conversely, W2 needs only to know the URL for Q1, which is the queue for which it is assigned to be a consumer.  As noted above, Q1 would likely "already exist," and the URL would be provided to both W1 and W2 -- perhaps when they were initially started up.  The incoming request could advise W2 of the URL of Q2, or W2 might always return its results to Q2, in which case W1 would not need to specify this in the original message.

The question of who creates queues and how the producer(s) and/or consumer(s) of the queue learn the queue URL is part of the architecture process -- there is most definitely no general principle that suggests the producer would be the most likely creator of the queue.  Who does what depends strongly on the reason the queues are being used and the nature of the workflow.